# Keep play books audio in the background?

Tags: google-play-books

Listening to books in Google Play Books read aloud and would like to know what needs to be done to keep the audio playing in the background so I load up other apps at the same time.

Rooted nexus 5 running 4.4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [google fourm's message](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/play/UX7uh6jh-uQ/mkXMzddLDAAJ), 17 Dec 16, this is a feature since version 3.11.19

> Quote danjaf
>
> Confirm this has been resolved in version 3.11.19
>
> I am running Marshmallow 6.0.1
>
> Thank you to the developer who heard our first world problems.

I have tested myself in at the current version of 4.4.9_RC07.213889590, released 21 September 2018, and can confirm it is still present.